Find the derivative of trace of matrix square root
I want to find following derivative:
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{Trace}(X^{1/2})}{\partial X},$$
where $X$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.
Similar questions have been asked many times but the answers do not agree with each other. In Derivative of $\text{Tr}(A B^{1/2})$ w.r.t. matrix $B$,
it says the answer is simply $\frac{1}{2}X^{-1/2}$. But in Matrix derivative of scalar function involving matrix square root, it seems that it is not that easy. Let $S^2=X$, then by product rule we have $\mathrm{d} X= S\mathrm{d} S+\mathrm{d} S S$. Since $\mathrm{d} S$ does not commute with $S$ in general, I can not get $\mathrm{d} S=\frac{1}{2}X^{-1/2}\mathrm{d} X$.
Thanks for any potential help.

How do you define $X^{1/2}$?

I do not understand. The answer by @greg takes care of the fact that $dS$ does not commute with $S$ through the use of vectorization. Look for the step when $dX$, $dS$ become $dx$, $ds$.

@Nicolas Let $X=U^T \Lambda U$ be its spectral decomposition. Then $X^{1/2}$ is defined by $U^T \Lambda^{1/2} U$, where $\Lambda^{1/2}=\mathrm{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},...,\sqrt{\lambda_n})$.

@TedBlack I'm wondering since $dS$ does not commute with $S$, if $dS = \frac{1}{2} X^{-1/2} dX$ is correct.

@kkw With this definition, can you work on the quantity $\mathrm{Tr}((X+H)^{1/2})$? By the way, $X$ must be positive definite if you want to define $X^{-1/2}$.

@Nicolas Yeah we can assume $X$ is positive definite. And what is $H$?

@kkw $H$ is a matrix whose dimensions are the same as $X$. By definition, the differential $df(X)$ of a function $f$ at the point (matrix here) $X$ is the linear map satisfying $f(X+H)=f(X)+df(X)[H]+o(||H||)$.

$dS=\frac{1}{2}X^{-\frac{1}{2}} dX$ is not correct. You have to apply the vec operator to factor out $dS$.

Have a look at the answers by @greg to my comments. They are very instructive and I think they point to an answer for your question.

@TedBlack Thanks. I get the point. $\mathrm{d} S \neq \frac{1}{2} X^{-1/2} \mathrm{d} X$ but $\mathrm{d} \mathrm{Tr} S = \frac{1}{2} (X^{1/2})^T: \mathrm{d} X$ because of the rearrangment property of trace.

Actually, the formula $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}X} \operatorname{tr}(f(X)) = f'(X)$ is often (but not always) true for matrices which do not commute with their derivatives. It is due to the linear and cycling properties of the trace, as exemplified by the simple case $f(x) = x^3$ below :
$$
\mathrm{d}\operatorname{tr}(X^3) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathrm{d}(X^3)) = \operatorname{tr}(X^2\mathrm{d}X + X\,\mathrm{d}X\,X + \mathrm{d}X\,X^2) = \operatorname{tr}(3X^2\mathrm{d}X)
$$
The posts you linked explain how to take advantage of these properties when the matrix square root $S = \sqrt{X}$ is defined through vectorization or power series, while Ted Black and Nicolas do the same work when $X$ is considered through its spectral decomposition on this very page. Here is another approach, somewhat specific to the case of the matrix square root.
Starting from the relation $\mathrm{d}X = \mathrm{d}(S^2) = S\mathrm{d}S + \mathrm{d}S\,S$, which turns out to be a Lyapunov equation for $\mathrm{d}S$, its solution admits the following representation, because $S$ is a priori positive-definite (due to the square root) and invertible (since the square root is not differentiable at the origin) :
$$
\mathrm{d}S = \int_0^\infty e^{-tS}\,\mathrm{d}X\,e^{-tS} \,\mathrm{d}t
$$
Thus, the linearity and the cyclicity of the trace permit to write :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}\operatorname{tr}S 
   &= \operatorname{tr}\mathrm{d}S \\
   &= \operatorname{tr}\int_0^\infty e^{-tS}\,\mathrm{d}X\,e^{-tS} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \operatorname{tr}\left(e^{-tS}\,\mathrm{d}X\,e^{-tS}\right) \mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \operatorname{tr}\left(e^{-2tS}\mathrm{d}X\right) \mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \operatorname{tr}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-2tS} \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}X\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}\left(S^{-1}\mathrm{d}X\right)
\end{align}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}X} \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{X}) = \frac{1}{2}X^{-1/2}
$$
in the end.

I will answer this question starting from scratch, with a different approach as the one used in the previous answers quoted in the OP.

Let $d\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and $X,H\in\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$. We endow $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the norm $|\bullet|$ and denote by $\|\bullet\|$ the corresponding subordinate norm on $\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$. We assume that $X$ is positive definite and $\|H\|\leq\delta<1$ ($H$ is not assumed positive definite).

Let $\mathbb{S}^d(0,1):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d\ \vert\ |x|=1\}$. We observe that $\mathbb{S}^d(0,1)\ni x\mapsto x^TXx\in(0,+\infty)$ is continuous; since $\mathbb{S}^d(0,1)$ is compact, we have:
$$\mu:=\min\{x^TXx\ \vert\ x\in\mathbb{S}^d(0,1)\}>0.$$
It follows that, for all $x\in\mathbb{S}^d(0,1)$,
$$x^T(X+H)x=x^T Xx+x^THx>\mu-\delta$$
that is $X+H$ is positive definite as well for $\delta<\mu$.

Next, for all $A\in\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$, let us write $\chi_A(\lambda):=\det(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-A)$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Recall that $\det:\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, with differential:
$$\mathrm{d}\det(A):\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})\ni B\longmapsto\mathrm{d}\det(A)[B]=\mathrm{Tr}(\widetilde{A}B)\in\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$$
where $\widetilde{A}$ is the cofactor matrix of $A$. We thus have:
\begin{align*}
\chi_{X+H}(\lambda)&=\det(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X-H)=\det(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)-\mathrm{d}\det(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)[-H]+o_{\|H\|\to0}(\|H\|)\\
%
&=\chi_X(\lambda)-\mathrm{Tr}(\widetilde{(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)}H)+o_{\|H\|\to0}(\|H\|).
\end{align*}
In particular, for $|\lambda|<\lambda_0$ with $\lambda_0>0$ greater than the spectral radius of $X$ (i.e. the modulus of the largest eigenvalue of $X$), we obtain:
$$|\chi_{X+H}(\lambda)-\chi_X(\lambda)|\leq C_{\lambda_0}\|H\|.$$
By Rouché's theorem, each root of $\chi_{X+H}$ lies in a disc centered on one root of $\chi_X$ with radius $\mathcal{O}_{\|H\|}(\|H\|)$. Hence, eigenvalues of $X+H$ and $X$ are close by a distance $\mathcal{O}_{\|H\|}(\|H\|)$.

Let us finally define for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R}$) positive definite:
$$A^\alpha:=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-A)^{-1}\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$
Above $\Gamma$ is a positive oriented contour in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the spectrum of $A$ is entirely contained inside $\Gamma$. By Cauchy's formula, the value of $X^\alpha$ is independant of the choice of $\Gamma$ as long as it does enclose the spectrum of $A$ -- check here for a quick derivation of the formula. Observe that $\Gamma$ can be taken inside $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \vert\ \mathrm{Re}(z)>0\}$ as the spectrum of $A$ lies on $(0,+\infty)$; it follows that $\lambda^\alpha=\exp(\alpha\log(\lambda))$ is well defined with $\log$ a determination of the complex logarithm with branch cut in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \vert\ \mathrm{Re}(z)\leq0\}$. Then we compute:
\begin{align*}
(X+H)^\alpha-X^\alpha&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma((\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X-H)^{-1}-(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1})\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda\\
%
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X-H)^{-1}H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda
\end{align*}
where we used the second resolvent identity. Notice that, by the precedent point, both the spectra of $X$ and $X+H$ lie on $(0,+\infty)$. Using Neumann series:
$$(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X-H)^{-1}=(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}(\mathrm{Id}-H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1})^{-1}=(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k(H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1})^k$$
which holds provided that $\|H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\|<1$ (that we can ensure by fixing $\delta<\max\{\|(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\|^{-1}\ \vert\ \lambda\in\Gamma\}$), we eventually discover:
\begin{align*}
(X+H)^\alpha-X^\alpha&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda\\
\quad&+\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\oint_\Gamma(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}(H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1})^kH(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda.
\end{align*}
The reader shall verify that it is indeed possible to intervert infinite sum and contour integral (using unfirom convergence) and that the last term above is $\mathcal{O}_{\|H\|}(\|H\|^2)$. This proves that $f_\alpha:\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})\ni X\mapsto X^\alpha\in\mathcal{M}_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$ is differentiable with differential:
$$\mathrm{d}f_\alpha(X)[H]=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\lambda^\alpha\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$
Whence:
$$\mathrm{d}(X\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(X^\alpha))[H]=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{d}f_\alpha(X)[H]).$$
For $\alpha=1/2$ this is:
$$\mathrm{d}(X\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}(X^{1/2}))[H]=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_\Gamma\mathrm{Tr}\Big((\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}H(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-X)^{-1}\Big)\sqrt{\lambda}\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$

I did not use the approach using the spectral decomposition of positive definite matrices as eigenvectors (and thus passage matrices) are not stable under small perturbations, see e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616493/eigenvectors-not-stable-under-matrix-perturbation.

This is a solution?!?

@TedBlack Indeed.

God bless you have found the secret to a long career; turn simple problems into intractable problems.

@TedBlack I love how you consider basic contour integration as « intractable »; I love how you do not consider that the OP says that the related previous answer is not satisfying as it is; I love how you consider that throwing in some Kronecker symbol and decomposition without any further details is satisfying just because you seem to only understand finite sums of matrix coefficients… Really, as if what you think was interesting…

Why don't you come up with an example for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $X$ that shows the simple elegance of your method? Hopefully this should give you a long deserved upvote...
